# hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details

Tags: git

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/TESTAZURESONAR/AzureSonar/_git/AzureSonar'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes,
hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

git pull origin master

Comment: Someone else pushed their updates to the server, and you have to fetch those updates  before you can push your updates.  Run `git pull` before you run `git push`.

Comment: Please do some basic research, this is very thoroughly covered already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull `remote changes` prior pushing your changes. Moreover, you need to specify the way of code merging. One way is to use rebase.

```bash
git pull <origin-name> <branch-name> --rebase
```

If the history is not related, you can use unrelated history flag.

```bash
git pull <origin-name> <branch-name> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: I would not recommend rebasing to an obvious beginner...

Comment: @JohnGordon interesting, why?

Comment: What is the benefit over a plain `git pull` ?

Comment: If you notice the error message mentioned `non-fast-forward` which `git pull` will not work since the default must be `fast-forward`. 

So since the history is diverged we need to specify how to reconcile either using `--rebase` or `--no-rebase`. In this case, if you use `--no-rebase` your history will be linear and you will no have access to those commits ever.

This is why I would recommend `rebase` to be able to checkout to those commits whenever needed.

Comment: @BassamA. Surely you have that backwards? "Rebase" means "create a new set of commits, as though this was the original point they branched from"; *without* `--rebase` (and without any other non-default settings) a merge commit will be created, preserving the original commits unchanged, but recording when you pulled in other people's contributions. The default is not "must be fast-forward", it's "try fast-forward, then fall back to creating a merge commit"; to force it to fail if it's can't fast-forward, you have to specify `--ff-only`, or an equivalent config setting.